Using the affinity module with a vector of transformations
I need to transform a GeoSeries with another vector of transformation of the same length.
For example I can do the following:
before = gdp.GeoSeries([box(0, 0, 1, 1), box(10, 10, 11, 11)])
after = before.translate(1, 1, 1)

which works well but how if I have a vector of translations:
translations = [[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2]]

and want to apply it so that each input geometry uses the corresponding translation?
What would be the best way you suggest to do that?

For future questions: please clarify the libraries you are using. In this case geopandas and shapely (shapely.geometry for box)

You can use a for loop, in case you want to translate the first item from before with the first item from translations, ... (although this is not very elegant):
import geopandas as gdp
from shapely.geometry import box

before = gdp.GeoSeries([box(0, 0, 1, 1), box(10, 10, 11, 11)])
translations = [[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2]]

translated_items = []
final_items = []

for n, item in enumerate(before):
    translation = translations[n]
    translated_items = before.translate(*translation)
    final_items.append(translated_items[n])
    
final_gs = gdp.GeoSeries(final_items)

Edit: Note that this might lead to (probably) undesired results if before and translations are of different lengths.

That works, thanks! I guess iteration is the only way here :) Can achieve similar result with an apply on the GeoDataFrame containing the GeoSeries too.
